# How $ionicHistory internally works?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

[image]I want to know how $ionicHistory internally works . If i call a function named goBack() inside  will it work fine . Or  any other tags i need to add in my html code . Please help me out with your suggestions .

i have used both

```js
  $scope.goBack = function() {
    console.log('Going back');
    $ionicViewService.getBackView().go();
  }

or



  $scope.goBack = function() {
    console.log('Going back');
  $ionicHistory.goBack();
  }
```

I tried both approach . everytime i am getting same output . you can see where 2nd logout is there , I am trying to navigate from that page to 1st page(1st logout ). But it's coming like this . Please help me out how to resolve this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/1.2.1/api/service/$ionicHistory/),it will track the views while user navigating in the application....an Ionic app is able to keep track of the previous view, the current view, and the forward view (if there is one).

And it contains some methods you can found in documentation....
coming to your case you need to write some code in your js according to your requirement like whether you want to go to previous view or next view and dont forgot to add or inject the dependency....
you need to use something like this

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
        //your code
     });
```

and

```
$ionicHistory.backView({
//your code
})
```

you may use `$ionicViewService` also and you can [find there](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/pGrxl)  how it will works

Comment: i have edited the post . can you please help me out to resolve this

Comment: both mean ur using both at a time or individually

Comment: I am using individually .

Comment: This is the code for html  <div class="col-xs-4">
          <a href="#"  id="back" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left pull-left"ng-click="goBack()"></span></a></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">  </div> and fr js file
  $scope.goBack = function() {
    console.log('Going back');
  $ionicHistory.goBack();
  }

Comment: Other codes may not work because i am using firebase to store or retrive data for this app .

Comment: just for your use case try with  window.history.back();    inside goback function instead of  $ionicHistory.goBack();

Comment: yes i tried with this $scope.goBack = function() {
         console.log('Going back');
  window.history.back(); 
  // window.history.go(-1);

        };   It not working .. no errors in console

Comment: okay no issues.....what is the problem while using ionic back??i am seeing like the  previous view not loading properly.....is that the same ur facing ??

Comment: i put the screenshot you can see the requested page is not displaying properly .. it's coming half as you can see in the snapshot(posted)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141517/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-s-p).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Sa E Chowdary Finally my code worked

Few changes i made in my js file

```js
    .state('app.profile', {
            cache: false,// disabled cache 
        url: './profile',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
               // templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
                templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
                controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
            },
            'fabContent': {
               template: ''
               
            }
        }
    })
    
    in my controller
    
    setTimeout(
  function() 
  {  $scope.goBack = function() {
         console.log('Going back');
$ionicHistory.goBack(); 
  // window.history.go(-1);

        };    
 
      }, 2000);
```

Main changes i did is disabled cache otherwise $ionicHistory was not behaving properly .

Again Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

yes `goBack()` will also work in your controller code.

use like this : `$ionicHistory.goBack();`

[Read the documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/1.2.1/api/service/$ionicHistory/)

Comment: i have edited the post . can you please help me out to resolve this